# Is this an ok use for the article element?

Tags: html, semantics, semantic-markup

I am re-writing some code for a new re-design and I am wondering if this is the best (pragmatically) semantic way to write this module?

This actually has 3-4 more items and will  slide items left/right, but I paired it down a bit for SO.

[image: Mockup]
[image]

Comment: +1 for nicely presented question.

Comment: What's the code editor? And what color theme is it?

Comment: Oh that's a theme i'm cooking up for Sublime Text :)
I should be updating the repo in the next few days http://bit.ly/LROq32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks fine to me. (As it satisfies the criteria as an independent item of content)

From the spec:

The article element represents a component of a page that consists of a self-contained composition in a document, page, application, or site and that is intended to be independently distributable or reusable, e.g. in syndication. This could be a forum post, a magazine or newspaper article, a blog entry, a user-submitted comment, an interactive widget or gadget, or any other independent item of content

Comment: Translation: A reusable, self-contained component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the use of `article` is fine here.

Whether the `article` elements should be inside of the `section` depends on the context of your page. If you use a sectioning element, you *should* give it a heading, too (but that's not a *must*!).

But your use of `dl` is **wrong**:

In your example, the name (`dt`) "Presented by" would have two values (`dd`): "Blue Iris Studio" **and** "19". The name "Walkins" would have the value "6.3". And the name "Miles Away" would have no value at all. This is not what you meant, I guess.

See the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20120329/the-dl-element.html#the-dl-element):

> Each group must consist of one or more names (`dt` elements) followed by one or more values (`dd` elements).

The order is important here: first 1 `dt`, then 1 or more (!) `dd`. Otherwise it would not be clear which `dt` and `dd` form a *group*.